# Swagger 2 accept xml instead of json

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a project with spring boot and I want to use swagger2 to document my json web services.

I have this configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2Config {

@Bean
public Docket welcomeMessageApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("My API")
            .description("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of ...")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("an url")
            .contact("contact")
            .license("")
            .licenseUrl("")
            .version("2.0")
            .build();
}
```

To read the documentation, I use this link : http://localhost:9081/v2/api-docs

In the swagger UI, it works fine. But when I try this link directly in my browser, I have this error :
[image]

With Firebug, I see that it accept XML content instead of JSON content.
[image]

How can I modify swagger configuration to accept JSON content ?

Answer (score 3):

You meet the problem because of the Spring MVC default get the server to render XML instead of JSON in a browser.
 [The official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-write-an-xml-rest-service) say:

> To get the server to render XML instead of JSON you might have to send an Accept: text/xml header (or use a browser).

So all you need to do is make the server render JSON in browser.

When you deep into the request in browser you'll see the Request Header:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

And if you debug into the spring boot, you will see the spring mvc will default delegate `HttpMessageConverters` include `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` and `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is to render json and `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` is to render xml.

They both have a field `supportedMediaTypes` which means what mediatypes are supported.

The value of `supportedMediaTypes` in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is:

[image]

The value of `supportedMediaTypes` in `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` is:

[image]

There is a 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8' in `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`.This is why browser render xml instend of json.

So you need add a custom `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` which support 'text/xml', for example :

```
    @Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        List<MediaType> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        list.add(new MediaType("text", "html", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        list.add(new MediaType("application", "*+json", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(list);
        converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

Try this and browser will render JSON instead of XML in browser, and all things right!

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Implementing this solution changed the server's response ContentType from "application/xhtml..." to "text/html", but didn't change it to "application/json" :(

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was updating the Maven dependencies for springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui.

The newest working combination for me was:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that the Swagger API returns XML when I tried to read it with a web-browser.

I resolved it with a different approach.
If you try calling the endpoint with some other tools, such as PostMan or Curl command tool, it would be return JSON correctly.

It looks like it happened in a web-browser only.

If you have Jackson XML extension in pom.xml, you may try this approach.
But if you need to return XML data as a response, please find out another solution.

This is my approach, add below Configuration which extends the WebMvcConfigurationSupport class to the project source code.

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConverterConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        HttpMessageConverter<?> target = null;

        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) { 
            if (converter.getClass() == MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.class) {
                target = converter;
            }
        }

        if (target != null) {
            converters.remove(target);
        }
    }
}
```

1. For regular GET type request, web-browser sends a request data to the endpoint, including the 'Accept' key in request header, having 'xml' value in it.
2. Besides, on the server-side, even if the response data type is JSON, and even if there's JSON message converter specified, Spring picks up the XML message converter first, if it is compatible with the JSON data.
3. On top of the above, the selection process is based on the order of 'Accept' value from request.

   - *You may debug the AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor, especially the writeWithMessageConverters method during the response
     process.*
4. In the selecting process, Spring picks up a proper converter based on the registered message converter list which is initialized on the process of the system initialization by the WebMvcConfigurationSupport.
5. The WebMvcConfigurationSupport provides extendMessageConverters to extend or modify the converter list.
6. So I tried to remove that special XML message converter from the list and it works.

**Although above solution worked for me, you may not use this approach.**

**Please find out another solution if you need to return XML data as a response.**